# How to check if asyncio create_server failed?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

So I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```py
class SomeClass:

    # Lots of code snipped

    def factory(self):
        raise RuntimeError

    def _run(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        try:
            self.server = self.loop.run_until_complete(
                self.loop.create_server(
                    self.factory, host=self.hostname, port=self.port
                )
            )
        except Exception as error:
            print("An Error Happened!")
            self._thread_exception = error
            return
        else:
            print("Success!")
        self.loop.run_forever()
```

Even with `factory()` hard coded to raise `RuntimeError`, I never saw "An Error Happened!" but I always get "Success!"

How do I check success/failure of `loop.create_server()` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I check success/failure of `loop.create_server()` there?

The problem is that `create_server()` was actually successful - it successfully created the server socket, bound it to the appropriate port, etc. Your factory is only called once someone connects, by which time `create_server()` has long returned.

To transfer the exception from your factory to some other code, you will need to transfer it manually, for example using an `Event`:

```
    def _run(self):
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self._main())

    async def _main(self):
        got_error = asyncio.Event()
        # invoke self.factory(), detecting errors
        async def wrapped_factory(*args):
            try:
                return self.factory(*args)
            except Exception as error:
                print("An Error Happened!")
                self._thread_exception = error
                got_error.set()
        self.server = await self.loop.create_server(
            wrapped_factory, host=self.hostname, port=self.port
        )

        # instead of loop.run_forever(), just wait for the error event
        while True:
            await got_error.wait()
            # here we handle the error and either exit the program
            # or keep running, depending on requirements
            got_error.clear()
```

Comment: Aaah, gotcha. So in essence factory() was "lazy-called". Thanks!